# Add Or Update EF Core7

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dbcontext, ef-core-7.0

What is the most efficient way to implement add or update using Entity Framework Core 7 for `IEnumerable<MyEntity> myentities`?

Tried to loop through each item and

```cs
myDBContext.CustomAddUpdate(item);
myDBContext.SaveChanges();
```

`CustomAddUpdate` method use entry for given entity and get the state Add or Update of `DBContext`.

Comment: The most _efficient way_ is to use `BULK INSERT`, another efficient approach is using `MERGE` as raw SQL using a table-valued parameter. Using EF in any way will be sloooow because it has to do RBAR.

Comment: Thank you @Dai Should the above work fine as well? Also can you post some link which I can refer or take my example and post the code which I can try and compare performance of to understand better?

Comment: _"Should the above work fine as well?"_ Hard to tell without seeing the implementation of `CustomAddUpdate`.

Comment: public void CustomAddUpdate(object item) { var entity = DBContext.Entry(item); switch (entity.state) { case EntityState.Added: Add(item); break; case Entity.Modified: Update(item); break;}}

Comment: @Fildor Apologies: Unable to edit question so added code as comment and just covered two cases to keep it simple

Comment: @TrialByFire EF is an ORM, not a database driver. The job of all ORMs is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects, not tables and rows. That, by definition, is slower than any bulk operation or SQL. There's no need for `AddOrUpdate` for individual objects because the DbContext already knows the state of the objects it tracks. If you want to *attach* new items, `Update` or `UpdateRange` will attach them in the Added or Modified state based on their primary key values and configuration. When `SaveChanges` is called, all Added objects are inserted, all Modified are updated

Comment: @TrialByFire don't add code as comments either. The comment shows an attempt to do what EF itself does automatically anyway and has no effect except perhaps causing bugs: if an object is in the Added state, Add it. But it's already Added, so there's no point to this. Same for `Modified` and `Update`

Comment: There are a few Entityframework nuget extensions that you can download, that enable BULK operations in SQL. 

It's just not included in the "native" microsoft package.

Comment: @MortenBork I've been wary of them because once you start using an EF extension from a NuGet package (as opposed to in fully customizable source-form) it means you're stuck behind if the package isn't updated whenever EF/EFCore gets updated.

Comment: @Dai I agree that framework packages are annoying like that, but EF-CORE is a framework package itself. 

And if it gets a new update, while you will have to remain on the older version until a new extension is developed, some of these nuget  extension are open source. Wost case, write a new extension, that DOES work with the newer version of EF .net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I think I understand what you want to do, please see if the following works for you:

```
public void AddOrUpdateRange(IEnumerable<MyEntity> myentities)
    {        
        var listForAddEntities= new List<MyEntity>();
        var listForUpdateEntities= new List<MyEntity>();

        foreach (MyEntity entity in myentities)
        {
            var entry = Entry(entity);
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Detached:
                case EntityState.Added:
                    listForAddEntities.Add(entity);
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    listForUpdateEntities.Add(entity);
                    break;
                //For Unchanged nothing to do

                default:
                    //anything you want to do
            }
        }
        AddRange(listForAddEntities);
        UpdateRange(listForUpdateEntities);
    }
```

Comment: Checking, will update. Thanks